# Android WebView findAll not working as expected

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview

I've got a webview fragment class like this:

```
public class WebviewFragment extends Fragment {

private WebView mWebView;
private String mFile;
private EditText mSearch;
private int mOccurrence;
private String mKeyword;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.webview_fragment, container, false);

    mSearch = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.search_bar_edit_text);
    mSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            fulltextSearch(s.toString());
        }
    });

    mWebView = (WebView) root.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.loadUrl(mFile);
    mWebView.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
    mWebView.requestFocus();
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }
    });

    return root;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    if (mOccurrence >= 0 && mKeyword != null) {
        scrollTo(mOccurrence, mKeyword);
    }
}

private void scrollTo(int occurrence, String keyword) {
    fulltextSearch(keyword);

    for (int i = occurrence; i >= 0; i--) {
        mWebView.findNext(true);
    }
}

public void fulltextSearch(String text) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        mWebView.findAll(text);
    }
    else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        mWebView.findAllAsync(text);
    }
}

public void findPrev() {
    mWebView.findNext(false);
}

public void findNext() {
    mWebView.findNext(true);
}
```

When i click into EditText (mSearch) it works normaly. It shows color output of occurences. What i need is to scroll to defined occurrence of keyword. The problem starts when i call methods from scrollTo. It shows nothing, nothing happen. Via debugs i know, theese functions is actually called, bud without any result... nothing happen. What am I doing wrong? Or it's a bug?

If there is a better way to scroll to specific occurence, i would be thankfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is example try this may be use full

[Find text in webview useing findall method](http://polamreddyn.blogspot.in/2013/03/high-lite-specific-text-in-android.html)

Answer (score 0):

Solution for other who will search this. How to modify onStart() method:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            if (mOccurrence >= 0 && mKeyword != null) {
                scrollTo(mOccurrence, mKeyword);
            }
        }
    });
}
```